# Using return value inside another function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have these two functions:

```
def check_channel_number(self):
    print "***************Channel Checker *********************" 
    print ''
    user_channel_number = int(re.sub('\D', '', raw_input("Enter a channel number, (3digit): "))[:3]);
    channel = ("channelNr= '%d'") % (user_channel_number)
    print channel
    # channel_search = channel + str(user_channel_number)
    datafile = file('output.txt')

    found = False
    for line in datafile:
        if channel in line:            
            found = True 
            print 'The channel number you entered is correct and will be deleted'
            return user_channel_number

    print 'The channel number you entered is not on the planner'
    return False
```

and

```
def delete_events(self):
    if user_channel_number == True:
        return 'The program number is correct and will be deleted'

        # action = 'DeleteEvent'
        menu_action = 'all'
        book = 'RECYC:687869882'
        arg_list = [('C:\\Users\\yke01\\Documents\\StormTest\\Scripts\\Completed'
                        '\\Utils\\UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py')]
        arg_list.append(' --action=')
        arg_list.append(action)
        arg_list.append(' --ip=')
        arg_list.append('10.10.8.89')
        arg_list.append(' --objectId=')
        arg_list.append(book)
        subprocess.call(["python", arg_list])

        print 'The program deleted successfully'
```

When I run my script, it says that `user_channel_number` is not defined globally. How can I use `user_channel_number` inside the `delete_events` function?

Comment: 1. You typecasted `user_channel_number` to `int`, then try to compare it to `True`. 2. `check_channel_number` always returns false. 3. Your return statement in `delete_events` stops all of the code after that from running. It looks like you're in a class? You can define `self.user_channel_number` to make it accessible for all methods in the class that you're in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functions can not share their local variables. You can return the value from the first and pass it to the second:

```
def check_channel_number(self):
    ...
    return user_channel_number

def delete_events(self):
    user_channel_number = self.check_channel_number()
    ...
```

Or save value on the object:

```
def check_channel_number(self):
    ...
    self.user_channel_number = user_channel_number
    ...

def delete_events(self):
    if self.user_channel_number:
         ....
```

Answer (score 11):

When you define a variable inside of a function, it is a local variable, meaning that it can only be accessed within that function.

**Within a Class**

It looks like you're inside a class, so you can make the variable accessible to all methods in the class by defining it like this:

```
def check_channel_number(self):

    self.user_channel_number = ...
```

And then in your second function, you can use it like the following:

```
def delete_events(self):

    if self.user_channel_number:
```

---

**Outside of a class**

If you aren't using methods inside of a class, you can instead use the `global` builtin.

For example,

```
def check_channel_number():

    global user_channel_number 
    user_channel_number = ...

def delete_events():

    if user_channel_number:

        ...
```

---

**Using a value returned from a function**

Instead in your first function, `check_channel_number()`, you can have it return `user_channel_number`. You can then call that function inside of `delete_events()`, like the following:

```
def check_channel_number():

    user_channel_number = ...
    return user_channel_number

def delete_events():

    if check_channel_number():

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think when you call the `check_channel_number` function, `user_channel_number` is defined in there, so when you call `delete_events`, it has gone out of scope, maybe something like this would help?

```
user_channel_number = check_channel_number()
delete_events()
```

I'd probably have the user_channel_number as an input to the delete function too, so it would turn into this: (where ucn is the `user_channel_number`)

```
def delete_events(self, ucn):
    if ucn == True:
        print 'The program number is correct and will be deleted'

        # action = 'DeleteEvent'
        menu_action = 'all'
        book = 'RECYC:687869882'
        arg_list = [('C:\\Users\\yke01\\Documents\\StormTest\\Scripts\\Completed'
                    '\\Utils\\UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py')]
        arg_list.append(' --action=')
        arg_list.append(action)
        arg_list.append(' --ip=')
        arg_list.append('10.10.8.89')
        arg_list.append(' --objectId=')
        arg_list.append(book)

        subprocess.call(["python", arg_list])

        print 'The program deleted successfully'
```

I have also changed `return 'The program number is correct and will be deleted'' to a print statement as I have a feeling the return would end the function before the other lines of code would be run

So the code would probably end up being something like:

```
user_channel_number = check_channel_number()
delete_events(user_channel_number)
```

EDIT:

just noticed it looks like your functions are part of a class,

in that case, you could do:

```
self.ucn = self.check_channel_number()
self.delete_events(self.ucn)
```

(or if you dont want to pass the user_channel_number into the function you could change `if user_channel_number:` to `if self. user_channel_number:`