# Pass variable from one function to second function python

Tags: python, function

I have two functions, and I need the variable I calculate in the first one for the calculation in the second function. My minimal working example is

```
import numpy.ma as ma
import numpy as np

data_1 = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18] 
error_1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def mask(data,error): 
      product = np.multiply(data,error)

def plot(perc):
    result = ma.masked_array(product, product >= (np.percentile(product, perc)))

mask(data_1,error_1)
plot(30)
plot(60)
plot(90)
```

This gives me the error

```
NameError: name 'product' is not defined
```

I know that 'product' is local. Let's pretend it takes up a lot of computing time to multiply both lists because of high resolution and whatnot. That's why I want to put it in a separate function. Of course I could put everything in one function like this:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
import numpy as np

data_1 = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18] 
error_1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def mask(data,error,perc): 
    product = np.multiply(data,error)
    result = ma.masked_array(product, product >= (np.percentile(product, perc)))
```

mask(data_1,error_1,30)
mask(data_1,error_1,60)
mask(data_1,error_1,90)

but with this I would calculate the product three times and it would take forever for the script to run. Is it clearer now what my problem is?

Comment: Because the `x` in second function is not defined and you are trying to do `x+1`!

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to combine both functions? In the original, the first function needs a lot of computing time and needs to computed only once. If I were to include in the second function, it would repeatedly be computed although it is not necessary

Comment: It seems like your minimal working example doesn't represent what you're trying to do in your real code. As it is, it just creates (or tries to create) local variables that don't get used for anything. Maybe you should give us something closer to your real code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using return value inside another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801789/using-return-value-inside-another-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You passed the value 3 in the first function but you didn't use it (I mean the x=3)
2. You made a calculation in the first function but you didn't return the result. The value of the x is passed by value, so it doesn't change oustide the function, it's just locally.
3. You have to pass the value x in the second function

   ```
   def mask(y):
       return y ** 2

   def plot(z, x):
       z = x + 1
       print(z)

   x = mask(3)
   plot(3, x)
   ```

The result of this code is 10.

Alternative: you can pass the value by reference or you can use globale variables..

Answer (score 0):

Change your function so they actually **return** values instead of assigning to local variables (which are destroyed once the function exits anyway):

```
def mask(y):
    return y ** 2

def plot(x, z):
    # do something with x here

x = mask(3) 
plot(x, whatever)
```